# Jqplot : highlighter not showing correct tooltip

Tags: jqplot

In my line chart I have done this,

```
highlighter: { 
               show: true,
               tooltipLocation: 'ne'
             },
```

On chart if I have one line with three data points then the points are plotting correctly but the wrong tooltip is being getting displayed.Specifically, the tooltip is getting shuffled i.e. for one data point it is showing tool tip of other data point.

Does display of tooltip depends on, what order data is coming?

Answer (score 0):

I got this!!!
Tooltip depends on the order of data points we are passing:)